# Should we use "final" keyword for @Auotowired inject Bean

Tags: java, autowired, final, spring-bean

I usually see in other codes which use final key word to inject Service Bean to Controllers, some code are not. So, what's the reason to use "final" in this. I know final variable that means it's immutable variable. I research some blogs that they say it relates to thread-safe.

Answer (score 5):

Use `final` when using [constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html):

> constructor injection lets the riskAssessor field be marked as final, indicating that it cannot be subsequently changed

Comment: But if I don't use final and use @Autowired in constructor and it still works normally?

Comment: @TamHuynhThanh if you use spring bean default singletone scope and write thread safe code then it will be thread safe, you don't have to mark as final

Comment: @user7294900 I am still not able to quite properly understand the use case of <final> keyword in constructor based injection. Can you please explain in a little more detail ?